# SSO using CAS with ASP.NET membership provider backend

Tags: asp.net, membership, single-sign-on, provider, cas

I'm trying to utilize [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) to perform SSO on the same domain name. however i can't really understand CAS. does CAS provides user management or i have to implement it myself ? can i integrate ASP.NET membership provider into CAS as the athentication provider ?

Thanks !

Comment: CAS mailing list expects that you're CAS expert !

Comment: Good luck. You may have the opposite problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does CAS provides user management or i have to implement it myself ?

No, it doesn't.

> can i integrate ASP.NET membership provider into CAS as the athentication provider ?

Yes, edit **deployerConfigContext.xml** in your CAS server and add your authentication handlers.

Comment: Could you provide more details about how to edit deployerconfigcontext.xml to work with asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

There's a full documentation of how to integrate CAS with ASP.NET form authentication at
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/ASP.NET+Forms+Authentication